# How do I reduce Elasticsearch scroll response time?

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I have a query returning ~200K hits from 7 different indices distributed across our cluster. I process my results as:

```
while (true) {
    scrollResp = client.prepareSearchScroll(scrollResp.getScrollId()).setScroll(new TimeValue(600000)).execute().actionGet();

    for (SearchHit hit : scrollResp.getHits()){
            //process hit}

    //Break condition: No hits are returned
    if (scrollResp.hits().hits().length == 0) {
        break;
    }
}
```

I'm noticing that the client.prepareSearchScroll line can hang for quite some time before returning the next set of search hits. This seems to get worse the longer I run the code for.

My setup for the search is:

```
SearchRequestBuilder searchBuilder = client.prepareSearch( index_names )
    .setSearchType(SearchType.SCAN)
    .setScroll(new TimeValue(60000)) //TimeValue?
    .setQuery( qb )
    .setFrom(0) //?
    .setSize(5000); //number of jsons to get in each search, what should it be? I have no idea.
    SearchResponse scrollResp = searchBuilder.execute().actionGet();
```

Is it expected that scanning and scrolling just takes a long time when examining many results? I'm very new to Elastic Search so keep in mind that I may be missing something very obvious.

My query:

```
QueryBuilder qb = QueryBuilders.boolQuery().must(QueryBuilders.termsQuery("tweet", interesting_words));
```

Answer (score 8):

`.setSize(5000)` means that each `client.prepareSearchScroll` call is going to retrieve 5000 records per shard. You are requesting back source, and if your records are big, assembling 5000 records in memory might take awhile. I would suggest trying a smaller number. Try 100 and 10 to see if you are getting a better performance.

`.setFrom(0)` is not necessary.

Comment: Yes, this definitely makes each scroll response faster. Now, are many smaller scrolls faster than one big scroll?

Comment: It depends on your setup. With very small batch size you get overhead of network communication, with very large batch size you get overhead of allocating large chunks of memory to collect and keep entire batch in memory. The sweet spot is somewhere in the middle, but you will have to figure it out yourself by experimenting with different batch sizes.

Comment: Ok good, I will try that. Another thing I've noticed is that the time it takes to scroll is not constant. After a while, the scrolls take much longer. I suspect I am filling up memory somewhere. I don't need the results after I process them, is there some sort of memory flush I should be doing in my loop?

Comment: What kind of query are you using?

Comment: Query is listed in the question now.

Comment: Cannot think of anything that would be causing significant slow down in this case. If you can make it to slow down to 10 seconds or more, it would be great if you could run [hot threads query](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/admin-cluster-nodes-hot-threads.html) while it's stuck in this state and publish results on the mailing list.

Comment: Ok I will give it a try. With setSize(100) the first several scrolls happen nearly instantly, after that they slow down to 6 or 7 seconds each. With setSize(1000) they slow to 30 seconds so I will use that.

Comment: By the way, how do I do that? client.admin().cluster().nodesStats(arg0, arg1) ?

Comment: http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/admin-cluster-nodes-hot-threads.html using `curl localhost:9200/_nodes/hot_threads`

Comment: If you do not need your data sorted, then changing the search_type to scan with your scroll will result in constant return times through the scroll.  Otherwise it will slowdown as you go deeper into the scroll sometime prohibitively so.

Comment: Regarding the question is many batches faster than large batches, I am experimenting with this right now and have found in my application that I can complete the scroll in 30s with a size of 10.  If I increase the size to 100, the total time goes to 300s.  Very odd IMO but sharing my experience for others to see.

Comment: Just wanted to add one more point of clarification to the size per shard as it may not be clear. If you use a size of 5000 and have the default of 5 shards in your index it will attempt to retrieve a batch of 25,000 documents.  Depending on your document size this could take an excessive amount of memory.

Answer (score 7):

I'm going to add another answer here, because I was very puzzled by this behaviour and it took me a long time to find the answer in the comments by @AaronM

This applies to ES 1.7.2, using the java API.

I was scrolling/scanning an index of 500m records, but with a query that returns about 400k rows.

I started off with a scroll size of 1,000 which seemed to me a reasonable trade-off in terms of network versus CPU.

This query ran terribly slowly, taking about 30 minutes to complete, with very long pauses between fetches from the cursor.

I worried that maybe it was just the query I was running and did not believe that decreasing the scroll size could help, as 1000 seemed tiny.

However, seeing AaronM's comment above, I tried a scroll size of 10.

The whole job completed in 30 seconds (and this was whether I had restarted ES or not, so presumably nothing to do with caching) - a speed-up of about 60x!!!

So if you're having performance problems with scroll/scan, I highly recommend trying decreasing the scroll size. I couldn't find much about this on the internet, so posted this here.

Comment: More you decrease scroll size, number of queries executed in total will be increased. Suppose your search result has 50K total hits and you keep scroll size to 10000 then query is executed 5 times which is less than 5000 times for scroll size 10. Query execution time has usually major part in total performance. So decreasing scroll size is not recommended. And scroll API is mainly for more than 10000 search results where you can paginate results.

Answer (score 2):

- Query data node not client node or
  master node
- Select the fields you need with `filter_path`property
- Set scroll size according your document size, there is no a magic rule, you must set value and try, and so on
- Monitor your network band width
- If it's not enough, let's go for some multi-threads stuff:

Think that elasticsearch index is composed of multiple shards. This design means you can parallelize operation.

Let's say your index has 3 shards, and your cluster 3 nodes (good practice to have more nodes than shards by index).

You could run 3 Java "workers", in a separate thread each, that will search scroll a different shard and node, and use a queue to "centralize" the results.

This way, you will have a good performance!

This is what the elasticsearch-hadoop library does.

To retrieve shards/nodes details about an index, use the https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-shards.html API.

Answer (score -1):

### You can read document here

[SearchScrollRequestBuilder](http://javadoc.kyubu.de/elasticsearch/v1.2.0/org/elasticsearch/action/search/SearchScrollRequestBuilder.html)!

> I think Timevalue is time to keep scrolling alive

```
setScroll(TimeValue keepAlive)
```

If set, will enable scrolling of the search request for the specified timeout.

### You can read more here :

[Scrolling](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-scroll.html#scroll-search-context)